# Scala: how to change this code in functional way?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have this List for example:

```
val list = List(
    Map("a" -> "John", "b" -> 20, "c" -> true), 
    Map("a" -> "Derp", "b" -> 10, "c" -> false), 
    Map("b" -> 8, "c" -> true),
    Map("a" -> "asdf", "b" -> 50, "c" -> true)
)
```

I have this code that process the above list and I want to change it into functional style and in the most efficient way:

```
var result = ""
breakable {
    for (m <- list) {
        if (m.get("a").isEmpty) {
            result = "Error A"
            break()
        }
        if (m.get("b").isEmpty) {
            result = "Error B"
            break()
        }
    }
}
```

In above code, if "a" doesn't exist, the if checking is only done once before going out of the loop. If "b" doesn't exist, the checking is done twice.

My attempt to change it to functional code:

```
val result = (for { 
    m <- list
    a = m.get("a").isEmpty
    b = m.get("b").isEmpty
    if a || b
} yield {
    if (a) 
        "Error A"
    else
        "Error B"
}).headOption.getOrElse("")
```

It doesn't look good as if "a" doesn't exist, the if checking will be done two times and if "b" doesn't exist, it will be done three times.

Also there is `.headOption.getOrElse("")` overhead. It will be nice if I can get string result directly.

Anyone can provide better solution?

Comment: To summarise, you want to check for the first Map that does not contain either an entry for "a" or for "b", and return "Error A" or "Error B" respectively? The answer probably involves collectFirst...

Comment: yep, but in original code, there is also index involved, so the result could be "Error A: 2". But I would like to make the problem isolated for simplicity.

Comment: `m.get(a).isEmpty`is maybe better expressed as  `!(m contains "a")` or `!m.isDefinedAt("a")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.view
    .map(m => if (m.get("a").isEmpty) "Error A" 
              else if (m.get("b").isEmpty) "Error B"
              else "")
    .find(_.nonEmpty)
    .getOrElse("")
```

Note the view to make it non-strict so it stops after the first failure element.

Slightly  neater with if statements as a partial function, not defined if neither "a" or "b" was in the map, and using contains

```
list.collectFirst{case m if !(m contains "a") => "Error A"
                  case m if !(m contains "b") => "Error B"}
    .getOrElse("")
```

With index

```
list.view
    .zipWithIndex
    .map{case (m,i) => if (m.get("a").isEmpty) "Error A:"+ i
                       else if (m.get("b").isEmpty) "Error B:" + i
                       else ""}
    .find(_.nonEmpty)
    .getOrElse("")
    //> res1: String = Error A:2
```

and using collectFirst

```
list.zipWithIndex
    .collectFirst{case (m, i) if !(m contains "a") => "Error A:" + i
                  case (m, i) if !(m contains "b") => "Error B:" + i}
    .getOrElse("")
```

Comment: For the 1st version with map and find, I think it also produces two times boolean checking for the "a": `if (m.get("a").isEmpty)` and `.find(_.nonEmpty)`.

Comment: For the 2nd version with `collectFirst`, that's really nice. But I'm a bit doubt whether collectFirst do boolean checking once or two times for the "a", because I saw in [decompiled code](http://pastebin.com/z5yaUFHS), the "a" empty checking is defined twice in `isDefinedAt` and `applyOrElse` method inside the collectFirst's anonymous partialFunction. But I had checked the scala library source code, it seems only `applyOrElse` that called for collectFirst.

Comment: In the source code of [collectFirst](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/cd50464cd019bc6a489a72b98293c30b91352bab/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L132), it calls [PartialFunction.runWith](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L136) which then called applyOrElse. Can you confirm is this correct?

Comment: No, it checks once. The find is checking the result (Error A, Error B or empty string). So only one lookup in the map

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to confirm since you've alreadt looked at the source. As a general point, I wouldn't obsess about microoptimisations until you know this is a real time consumer in your app. Clarity matters too

Comment: Who knows I was wrong :). The source code is huge and I seldom visit there.

Comment: I'm no expert either.. But it seems to me applyOrElse is used to avoid having to call .isDefined. Looks OK to me

Comment: For your 1st solution, I'm still not sure. Isn't it the `.find(_.nonEmpty)` will iterate again the previous mapped list and do additional boolean checking with the predicate `_.nonEmpty`? If you look at the imperative code, there is only one boolean checking for the "a" case, if it's empty, then it breaks the loop.

Comment: Put a `println` in the `map` just before the `if`. It will print once per element. That's the point of the `view`.  The `map` function isn;t even called on each element until `find` needs to test the result of the `if...else.`. Yes, there's an extra test but it's just testing the result for emptiness, not re-testing whether 'a' or 'b' exist. And if you're microoptimising, note that break() in the imperative case is implemented with an exception which is not a cheap operation.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/util/control/Breaks.scala#L1

Comment: I know that about how view works, I'm talking about the extra test in `find`. I still can optimize the imperative code by moving the code into a function and use return for breaking :). Anyway, thanks for the answer, good job for the collectFirst.

Comment: Nope. Return uses exceptions too.

Comment: Oh well, that's a pity.

Comment: Btw, why you don't use list.view for the list.zipWithIndex.collectFirst ?

Comment: (this is getting a bit chatty). Because I wasn't obsessing with microoptimisations? :-P Also, collectFirst won't traverse the whole List so the saving is minimal, and there's an overhead to .view so it's not worth it unless you're saving an expensive operation (or the list is very long)

Comment: The question is about how to do it with functional and efficient way anyway. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @suud Did this answer satisfy your question?  If so, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for addendum, the other viable solution is by using recursion:

```
def getError(list: List[Map[String, Any]]): String = {
    if (list.nonEmpty) {
        val m = list.head
        if (m.get("a").isEmpty) 
            "Error A"
        else if (m.get("b").isEmpty)
            "Error B"
        else
            getError(list.tail)
    } else ""
}
```